# jQuery - add class to active slide in expanding image menu

Tags: jquery

Hi I've adapted this tutorial slider (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/03/16/expanding-image-menu/) to be responsive and not use image backgrounds. I need to be able to adjust the opacity of the list items depending on whether or not it is expanded, but I'm struggling to find a way to add an active class to the expanded item. I think I should do this by using .addClass but I cant figure out where to do this and how it should be written. Any guidance much appreciated.
Thanks
Charlie

```
        $(function() {
            var $menu               = $('#ei_menu > ul'),
                $menuItems          = $menu.children('li'),
                $menuItemsImgWrapper= $menuItems.children('a'),
                $menuItemsPreview   = $menuItemsImgWrapper.children('.ei_preview'),
                totalMenuItems      = $menuItems.length,

                ExpandingMenu   = (function(){
                    /*
                        @current
                        set it to the index of the element you want to be opened by default,
                        or -1 if you want the menu to be closed initially
                     */
                    var current             = 8,

                    /*
                        @anim
                        if we want the default opened item to animate initialy set this to true
                     */
                    anim                = true,
                    /*
                        checks if the current value is valid -
                        between 0 and the number of items
                     */
                    validCurrent        = function() {
                        return (current >= 0 && current < totalMenuItems);
                    },
                    init                = function() {
                            /* show default item if current is set to a valid index */
                        if(validCurrent())
                            configureMenu();

                        initEventsHandler();
                    },
                    configureMenu       = function() {
                            /* get the item for the current */
                        var $item   = $menuItems.eq(current);
                            /* if anim is true slide out the item */
                        if(anim)
                            slideOutItem($item, true, 900, 'easeInQuint');


                        else{
                                /* if not just show it */
                            $item.css({width : '60%'})
                            .find('.ei_image')
                            .css({left:'0px', opacity:1});

                            /*

                            .find('.ei_descr')
                            .css({display:'block'});/

                                /* decrease the opacity of the others */
                                $menuItems.not($item)
                                          .children('.ei_preview')
                                          .css({opacity:0.2});




                        }
                    },
                    initEventsHandler   = function() {
                            /*
                            when we click an item the following can happen:
                            1) The item is already opened - close it!
                            2) The item is closed - open it! (if another one is opened, close it!)
                            */
                        $menuItemsImgWrapper.bind('click.ExpandingMenu', function(e) {
                            var $this   = $(this).parent(),
                            idx     = $this.index();

                            if(current === idx) {
                                slideOutItem($menuItems.eq(current), false, 1500, 'easeOutQuint', true);
                                current = -1;

                            }
                            else{
                                if(validCurrent() && current !== idx)
                                        slideOutItem($menuItems.eq(current), false, 250, 'jswing');

                                current = idx;
                                    slideOutItem($this, true, 250, 'jswing');
                            }
                            return false;
                        });
                    },
                        /* if you want to trigger the action to open a specific item */
                        openItem            = function(idx) {
                            $menuItemsImgWrapper.eq(idx).click();
                                                            },
                        /*
                        opens or closes an item
                        note that "mLeave" is just true when all the items close,
                        in which case we want that all of them get opacity 1 again.
                        "dir" tells us if we are opening or closing an item (true | false)
                        */
                    slideOutItem        = function($item, dir, speed, easing, mLeave) {
                        var $ei_image   = $item.find('.ei_image'),

                        itemParam   = (dir) ? {width : '60%'} : {width : '5%'},
                        imageParam  = (dir) ? {left : '0px'} : {left : '5%'};

                            /*
                            if opening, we animate the opacity of all the elements to 0.1.
                            this is to give focus on the opened item..
                            */
                        if(dir)
                        /*
                                alternative:
                                $menuItemsPreview.not($menuItemsPreview.eq(current))
                                                 .stop()
                                                 .animate({opacity:0.1}, 500);
                         */
                            $menuItemsPreview.stop()
                        .animate({opacity:0.1}, 1000);
                        else if(mLeave)
                            $menuItemsPreview.stop()
                        .animate({opacity:1}, 1500);

                            /* the <li> expands or collapses */
                        $item.stop().animate(itemParam, speed, easing);
                            /* the image (color) slides in or out */
                        $ei_image.stop().animate(imageParam, speed, easing, function() {
                                /*
                                if opening, we animate the opacity to 1,
                                otherwise we reset it.
                                */
                            if(dir)
                                $ei_image.animate({opacity:1}, 2000);
                            else
                                $ei_image.css('opacity', 0.2);
                        });
                    };

                    return {
                        init        : init,
                        openItem    : openItem
                    };
                })();

            /*
            call the init method of ExpandingMenu
            */
            ExpandingMenu.init();

            /*
            if later on you want to open / close a specific item you could do it like so:
            ExpandingMenu.openItem(3); // toggles item 3 (zero-based indexing)
            */
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted (I have'nt read the article), it's the `slideOutItem`, a function that expands or hides the elements.

```
    // ...

    /*
        if opening, we animate the opacity to 1,
        otherwise we reset it.
    */
    if(dir)
    {
        $ei_image.animate({opacity:1}, 2000);

        // Add .active
        $ei_image.addClass('active');
    }
    else
    {
        $ei_image.css('opacity', 0.2);

        // Remove .active
        $ei_image.removeClass('active');
    }

    // ...
```

Comment: Too bad, I can't really help without seeing the actual implementation. Setting breakpoints in Firebug revealed that it is this fragment of code that expands or hides the elements...

Comment: Oops. There was an error, it should have been `addClass('active')` and `removeClass('active')` (no punctuation). Edited my answer.